# Voxel sparse octrees for indirect illumination

Tags: algorithm, rendering, lighting, voxels

I don't understand the use of voxel sparse octrees for indirect illumination calculations. First of all, what exactly is happing? We're rendering the scene as usual with diffuse lighting. In the meantime, we're maintaining the octree of our scene. But when do we use it and for what exactly?

Comment: Take a look at [these slides](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2012/presentations/SB134-Voxel-Cone-Tracing-Octree-Real-Time-Illumination.pdf). It isn't to complicated if you understand how indirect illumination works in a raytracer; so start there.

Comment: @Jason I've already seen these slides. My main question is: Is building up a voxel sparse octree an *addition* to the traditional rendering process, meaning that we use it at some shader stages to receive some information which this data structure provides? Or do we render the scene entirely different?

Comment: Slide 9 clearly states that the scene is rasterized using the traditional rendering pipeline. The secondary rays use the SVO. In a traditional game renderer, these secondary rays are queried with a shadow map, which only lets them go towards the light (or the direction the map was rendered in). The SVO lets them go in any direction, which produces the nice global illumination.